# Trouble Running Processing P3D Renderer

Tags: processing

I'm trying to run a simple sketch that draws a grey box in Processing 2.0. For some reason, it's just freezing up as soon as it hits the Size(100, 100, P3D) line. I'm running it on a Windows XP laptop, Service Pack 3, with 448 mb of ram. I know it's not processing power, because task manager says that only 1% of the ram is used up. I looked online and can't find anything like this. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Any errors ? Also use `size(100,100,P3D);` not `Size(100,100,P3D);`

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped on the post, and I have the capitalization correct in the program. Also, it's not throwing up any errors. That's part of the reason I'm so confused.

Comment: What version of Processing are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Processing 2.0

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

If your computer does not have a graphics driver, P3D will not work at all. Try going to the computer manufacturer's website and check for driver updates.
Also, while updating your drivers, never visit sites like driverupdate.com. I have tried them and they don't work, as well as filling your computer with malware.